# Streaming Web Service with Complex Queries

Tags: design-patterns, streaming, protocols, odata, feed

I'm currently trying to build out a rather complex API for third-party consumption.  The API would provide the ability for consumers to query a data-set on a complex set of criteria and receive an optionally paged set of results.

The best solution I've seen so far is OData.  In addition to one-time queries, the consumer should be able to receive new results on a streaming basis.

I've considered two possible ways to handle this.

1) Have the consumer register a callback which is used to disseminate new content
2) Maintain an HTTP Web-socket on a server-to-server basis through which a query would become a pub-sub topic.

Both of these are not ideal for numerous reasons. I'd love some insight into how others have solved these problems and whether I should be barking up a different tree.

Thanks!